# Get List Of values from an inner query in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have a doc like

```
{
 "order_id" : 987,
 "product_id": 1234,
 "order_date": "2020-10-01",
 "day of week": "Monday",
 "currency": "USD"
..
},
{
 "order_id" : 789,
 "product_id": 4321,
 "order_date": "2020-11-01",
 "day of week": "Monday",
 "currency": "USD"
..
}
```

Now i want all the list/array of all order_id(s) which holds

1. currency is not null
2. "day of week" is 'Monday'

for an inner query in "terms" where i am searching the order_id(s)

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "order_id": [
              **{
                "match": {
                  "day of week": "Monday"
                }
              },
              {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "currency"
                }
              }**
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "order_date"
          }
        }]
      }
    }
..
..
}
```

I want the query of list of all order_id(s) instead the existing inner query (bold).

Comment: this is not very clear **query of the list of all order_id(s) instead of the existing inner query (bold).**, can you also provide a sample of your expected result.

Comment: did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from u :)

Answer (score 0):

Try out this below search query, and refer ES official documentation on [Boolean query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

> Query to find list/array of all order_id(s) which holds
>
> 1. currency is not null
> 2. "day of week" is 'Monday'

Adding a working example with the same index data and taking default mapping.

**Search Query:**

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "day of week.keyword": "Monday"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "exists": {
                        "field": "currency"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my-index",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.0,
        "_source": {
          "order_id": 987,
          "product_id": 1234,
          "order_date": "2020-10-01",
          "day of week": "Monday",
          "currency": "USD"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my-index",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.0,
        "_source": {
          "order_id": 789,
          "product_id": 4321,
          "order_date": "2020-11-01",
          "day of week": "Monday",
          "currency": "USD"
        }
      }
    ]
```